# setText method not looping properly compared to appendText method in google-docs using google-apps-scripts for doc template placeholders

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have made resume template in google docs with placeholders within the document to then later run a script that fills them with actual content. Then I'm using bookmarks to easily replace the text within the element when the placeholders are removed.

Full code:

```
function ResumeUpdate() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();



  var Content = {
    personal_info: {
      first_name: "Luis",
      middle_name: "mymiddlename",
      last_name: "lastname Merchant",
      address_line_1: "111 grdvvv Ct NE",
      address_line_2: "Concord, NC 00000",
      phone_number: "(704) 450-9196",
      email_address: "mygmail@gmail.com",
      linkedin_url: "LINKEDIN GOES HERE... "},

    resume_body: { 
      objective: "OBJECTIVE GOES HERE... ",
      experience: ["EXPERIENCE GO HERE... "],
      education: [{
        institution: "Intitution",
        degree: "Degree",
        course_work: ["course work... "]}],
      skills: ["SKILLS GO HERE... "],
      leadership: ["LEADERSHIP GOES HERE... ","second"],}
  };
  var pinfo = Content.personal_info;
  pinfo.full_name = pinfo.first_name + " " + pinfo.middle_name + " " + pinfo.last_name;

  //set street address.

  for (var key1 in Content) {
    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    //if (Content.hasOwnProperty(key1)) {

      var obj = Content[key1];
      for (var prop in obj) {
          // skip loop if the property is from prototype
          //if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

            // your code
            var property_name = String(prop).toUpperCase();
            var property_const = obj[prop];
            var property_placeholder = "{" + String(prop) + "}";
            //Logger.log(String(prop));
            propertyUpdate(property_name, property_const,property_placeholder,doc,false);
          //}
      }
    //}
  }

  //getAllElements(body,1);
}
function lookUpPropert() {

}

function propertyUpdate(property_name, property_const,property_placeholder,doc) {
  var bookmark_ids = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var temp = body.findText(property_placeholder);
  var position = null;

  if(temp != null) {
    temp = temp.getElement();
    position = doc.newPosition(temp,0);
    temp.setText(property_const);
    Logger.log(temp);
    bookmark_ids.setProperty(property_name, doc.addBookmark(position).getId());
  } else if(bookmark_ids.getProperty(property_name) != null) {
    temp = bookmark_ids.getProperty(property_name);
    Logger.log(temp);
    position = doc.getBookmark(temp).getPosition();
    temp = position.getElement().getChild(0);
    Logger.log(temp);
    temp.setText(property_placeholder);
    //bookmark_ids.setProperty(property_name, doc.addBookmark(position).getId());
  }
}

function getAllElements(element,k) {
  if(element.getType() != DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) {
    for(var i = 0;i < element.getNumChildren();i++) {
      var currentElement = element.getChild(i);

      Logger.log("DEPTH: " + k);
      Logger.log("    Element "+ (i+1) + ": "+ currentElement.getType());
      getAllElements(currentElement,k+1);
    }
  }
}
```

The script fails to run properly in this function. specifically in else if statement where the setText function is:

```
function propertyUpdate(property_name, property_const,property_placeholder,doc) {
  var bookmark_ids = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var temp = body.findText(property_placeholder);
  var position = null;

  if(temp != null) {
    temp = temp.getElement();
    position = doc.newPosition(temp,0);
    temp.setText(property_const);
    Logger.log(temp);
    bookmark_ids.setProperty(property_name, doc.addBookmark(position).getId());
  } else if(bookmark_ids.getProperty(property_name) != null) {
    temp = bookmark_ids.getProperty(property_name);
    //Logger.log(temp);
    position = doc.getBookmark(temp).getPosition();
    temp = position.getElement().getChild(0);
    //Logger.log(temp);
    temp.setText(property_placeholder);
    //bookmark_ids.setProperty(property_name, doc.addBookmark(position).getId());
  }
}
```

If I change the following line that I believe is giving me trouble.

```
temp.setText(property_placeholder);
```

Changing the statement above to the one below will make the script run just fine.

```
temp.appendText(property_placeholder);
```

I have also tried working around it. Replacing it with the following statements, but it also fails to run properly.

```
temp.clear();
temp.appendText();.
```

I want to know whether I can work around it to make it run properly or if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance. I have looked for questions with similar problems but I have not found any.

Logger.log output in first run:

```
[18-04-24 17:28:33:386 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:28:33:472 EDT] id.w0ss48exdha8
[18-04-24 17:28:33:480 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:28:33:547 EDT] id.2fgia2ykm2ll
[18-04-24 17:28:33:556 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:28:33:631 EDT] id.q935y6ouj0q
[18-04-24 17:28:33:640 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:28:33:708 EDT] id.xrizd1yc7i7h
[18-04-24 17:28:33:716 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:28:33:795 EDT] id.mkx1yvl8zw
[18-04-24 17:28:33:803 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:28:33:875 EDT] id.rzbgk2n8la5n
```

Logger.log output second run:

```
[18-04-24 17:29:14:051 EDT] id.w0ss48exdha8
[18-04-24 17:29:14:056 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:29:14:099 EDT] id.2fgia2ykm2ll
[18-04-24 17:29:14:103 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:29:14:146 EDT] id.q935y6ouj0q
[18-04-24 17:29:14:150 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:29:14:192 EDT] id.xrizd1yc7i7h
[18-04-24 17:29:14:196 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:29:14:239 EDT] id.mkx1yvl8zw
[18-04-24 17:29:14:243 EDT] Text
[18-04-24 17:29:14:287 EDT] id.rzbgk2n8la5n
[18-04-24 17:29:14:291 EDT] Text
```

at this point the there are no errors in the script but the document output is wrong even doe the bookmark ids match the ones from the previous run.

Logger.log output third run:

```
[18-04-24 17:30:47:142 EDT] id.w0ss48exdha8
```

The script throws the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot call method "getPosition" of null. (line 76, file "Code")
```

this makes senses since the first bookmark is deleted in the second run by setText(); however, it still doesn't explain why the document output is formatted wrong the second run. The error thrown on the third run would be fixed by replacing the bookmarks with the place_holders, therefore, it would run looking for placeholders and not bookmarks. This process would repeat every two run of the script.

Comment: I see you tried logging the temps value. Can you show us what was logged?

Comment: Just edited the question with Logger.log outputs